# How to ignore custom attribute of class in one of its object(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-attributes

I have created custom attribute that is used on `Translation` class, which is applied as following:

```
[ValidateTranslationDictionary]
public class Translations : Dictionary<string, string>{  }
```

The attribute code is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidateTranslationDictionaryAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateTranslationDictionaryAttribute() : base() { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DoSomeValidationHere(); //....
        return ValidationResult.Success; //for example
    }
}
```

My default scenario is to apply the validation attribute on all objects of the `Translation` class  (currently work perfectly),

but in some cases I need to skip this validation on some object, example:

```
public class Test{
    public Translations WithValidation{ get; set; }
    public Translations WithoutValidation{ get; set; }
}
```

There is a way to **not** run the validation on `WithoutValidation` property of `Test` class but keep it on the others objects?

Also I tried to add boolean to the attribute as flag to run the validation, and put the attribute on both class and property, but the attribute validator run 2 times, first from property, and the second call from the class

**hint**: can I add another attribute called for example `IgnoreValidationAttribute` , and make it skip `ValidateTranslationDictionary` attribute?

Comment: And how should a class know which of its objects to validate? Looks a bit like a x-y problem to me.

Comment: @Klamsi hello, it is now validate each object of Translation class. can i add another attribute called for example IgnoreValidationAttribute, and make it skip ValidateTranslationDictionary attribute?

Comment: Why not use a bool in your `Translations` constructor "bool DoValidation"?

Comment: @Klamsi i tried to add boolean property to the attribute as a flag to run the validation or not, and put the attribute on both class and property, but the attribute validator run 2 times, first from property, and the second call from the class

Comment: I have not yet understood the need for attributes for this problem

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that `Translations` object does not really require validation, at least not all of the time.

Why not approach this another way.

- Leave the `Translations` class as it is without the attribute.
- Then apply the attribute on attribute level

```
public class Test{
    [ValidateTranslationDictionary]
    public Translations WithValidation{ get; set; }
    public Translations WithoutValidation{ get; set; }
}
```

And if you need the exact same class with validations, then

```
[ValidateTranslationDictionary]
public class ValidTranslations: Translations
```